# Rounding Time off to MicroSeconds

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How do you round a timestamp down to microseconds in python?

I have a time stamp like this.

```
   2016-05-07 08:29:58.387888640
```

I have formatted this using format

```
   %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f
```

from the dataframe like this

```
  pd.to_datetime(time['Out'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

However, this gives it down to the nano second level. I want this to round off at microsecond but not sure what the best way of doing this would be. Can you kindly let me know?

Comment: You could cut truncate the string: `time['Out'].str[:23]`

Answer (score 1):

To display the right amount of decimals, you can use the `strptime` method of the timestamp - its `%f` directive is set in to be in [microseconds](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
tstamp = pd.Timestamp('2016-05-07 08:29:58.387888640')
tstamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

This simply truncates the equivalent string into `'2016-05-07 08:29:58.387888'`.

If you're concerned about the rounding errors, you should also call the `round` method defined for pandas' timestamps and set resolution:

```
tstamp.round("1 us").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Note how the last digit is now properly rounded: `'2016-05-07 08:29:58.387889'`.